# Logic of Navigations in DXA 1.6

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.6, navigation

I found Navigations' models (`NavigationLinks.cs` in `Sdl.Web.Common`) and saw the source code of controller `NavigationController`.
However, it's hard to understand logic of its realization. Is there any document about the logic of navigations in DXA 1.6?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? If so, can you be more specific in what you are looking for? http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v6/GUID-4A757BE5-AED2-4AEE-B9A0-E2A1BEE30C49